# Left padding on div mysteriously disappears when screen updates

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a simple app with a couple search boxes at the top, a results list on the left, and a detail display on the right.

The results list often has a scrollbar (which is on the right). When I hide and then show items on the results list, the scrollbar sometimes overlaps the detail section on the right.

I've deployed a copy so you can see the actual app: [dotadb.cloudapp.net](http://dotadb.cloudapp.net).

To reproduce the issue:

1. Go to the app. Observe that the the vertical scrollbar on the Hero Options list does not overlap the detail section on the right.
2. Type a hero name in the search box with no matches, like "sifsjfhfd".
3. Delete the text from the search box. Observe that the dropdown list scrollbar now overlaps the detail section.

Even stranger, typing a single letter in the search box corrects the issue. None of my CSS or javascript should be causing this to display differently, to the best of my understanding.

The only clue I have is this:

When the scrollbar is overlaying the detail, in Chrome dev tools, I can go to line 1573, which is:

```
<td rowspan="2" style="padding-left: 8px" valign="top">
```

I set the "padding-left" to 0px (in the inspector), then set it back to 8px. The problem is now fixed (the scrollbar no longer overlaps the detail section). Now, maybe that *should* mean something to me, but instead it's just really confusing.

Help & insight would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Unless clearly specified, column width inside tables is updated based on contents. You shouldn't use tables for layout, unless you know exactly what you're doing, especially if you plan to manipulate cell contents. Besides, they're really heavy on the rendering engine, compared to most other elements (because of the auto-adjusting scripts). The worst part is you don't have control over those scripts. They're at browser level. My advice: don't use tables for layout. Use `<divs>` and everything will be under your control. Not to mention you're using Bootstrap, so layouting is a breeze.

Comment: @Andrei, thanks, I'll switch to using divs instead of tables. Bad habit from using MS Word and the like. :) As for using bootstrap, I've never actually used it on purpose--can you point me toward a good resource to get me started?

Comment: Bootstrap grid system: [v4 here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/). [v3 here](http://bootstrapdocs.com/v3.0.0/docs/css/#grid)

Comment: You're a gentleman and a scholar.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu All right, I've switched to using the bootstrap layout and, after lots of wrong guesses, I've managed to solve the problem. It also incidentally allowed me to solve a number of alignment and display issues, so I'm glad you recommended doing this the "right way" instead of just offering a quick fix. Thanks!